# LED not outputting square wave signal

Tags: led, signal, waveform, light-sensor

I'm working on a sensor similar to an oximeter that measures light attenuation through a medium. I have an LED on one side, and an IC photodiode with on-chip transimpedance amplifier (OPT101) on the other. The photodiode measures the LED output. To make the signal as clean and stable as possible, I run the LED through a current regulator [(PSSI2021SAY)](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSSI2021SAY.pdf). Here is a simplified schematic:
[image]

The problem I'm encountering is that when I switch on and off the LED, I do not get a square wave signal. When I shut the LED off, the falling edge is a square wave as I would expect - which makes me think the issue is not from the OPTI101 . However when I turn the LED on, the output signal is not square as the signal spikes, and then levels off. This happens on the order of 5 seconds which is not intuitive to me. I thought that LEDs have a much faster response time than this, so id be surprised if this is due to an LED warmup period. The OPTI101 also has a very fast response time (~50ns), and as the falling edge is square, I don't suspect it very much. Ive run may tests where I've removed all capacitors from the circuit to see if that was the issue, but still not getting square waves. (I've even run tests where I power the LED independently using a separate battery and a switch to further reduce capacitance). Ive run this experiment with/without the current regulator as well. Here are some plots of the signals I'm getting:

Turning LED on creates spike:
[image]
turning LED off produces nice square:
[image]
Full view:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why I'm not getting square waves? Do LEDs really require a warmup period on this timescale?

EDIT: some updates on more tests I've performed:

1. Instead of turning on/off LEDs, I tried dropping the current, then turning it back up. I found that the issue still remains, but what's interesting is that there is a negative dip when it goes down as if the LED output has inertia. I think this too suggests that the issue is warmup related. As the current drops, the temperature drops, and the LED efficiency increases. Thus the initial drop would be from the prior low efficiency state at high current, then as the LED cools down, efficiency increases, and the light output increases. Here is a plot of the data (ignore x axis label):

[image]

2. I also tried mechanically blocking the light. THIS WORKS! This suggests that the OPTI101 is not to blame here (though I did not suspect it anyhow). So this further points at the LED system as being the culprit. And I still think it is temperature related, which if it is in fact the case, I don't see any solution for electronically...

Heres a plot of the result:
[image]

I must say that I'm still skeptical that it is impossible to get a square wave from an LED, given the fact that other instruments do operate by flashing LEDs, and they presumably don't have this issue... so question still stands!

Comment: If you would replace the LED with a resistor + diode with equivalent values, will you observe the same characteristics? Is the microcontroller not connected to the ground, or is that just the simplified schematic? If you would remove the ADC and simplify the circuit, are there any changes in the characteristics? I would remove components from the software and from the circuitry to make the simplest replicator of the problem (the process could pin point to cause of the culprit)

Comment: That current regulator says how to switch it on and off (Fig. 6 in the datasheet), which is not what you're doing. Have you tried the recommended method?

Comment: @AntonKrug I have already tried replacing the current source with a resistor and I still observe the same characteristics. This schematic is greatly simplified and the controller is grounded in actuality.

Comment: @user1850479 Yes, in reality I am switching on/off the regulator from the current source. But I've tried both switching on/off the regulator like suggested in the data sheet, and using a mosfet on the LED like shown in my schematic. All iterations produce the same characteristic spike/decay

Comment: What current are you driving through the LED?

Comment: Have you monitored the LED current? Does it look square(ish) or more like your photosensor output? What does your circuit layout look like physically? PCB or breadboard?

Comment: @KevinWhite Its running at 2 mA right now. The LED (AP2012SF4C-P22) is actually rated for 50mA. I know that sounds like im running it low, but actually I've done this same experiment running it with 30mA to see if that was the problem,, and it actually made the issue worse and more pronounced. Is it normal for an LED to have a 4 second warmup period?

Comment: @brhans I haven't monitored the LED current while it is in operation. It sounds like a good idea though. I may be able to put a shunt resistor in there and make some measurements.

Comment: Ok 2mA should be low enough to avoid thermal issues with the LED. What is the power supply doing at this time? Have you measured it accurately during operation? With these small changes an ordinary scope may not have good enough resolution.

Comment: Have you looked at the battery voltage with your scope during the on-off cycling? Battery voltage can sag as the LED draws current, and there can be a time-varying effect due to battery internal chemistry. Try separate supplies for LED and sensor.

Comment: I would suggest the following experiment: 1) keep your schematic as it is; 2) put some light-proof box over your LED; 3) take a separate power source, another LED of the same type and a simple resistor; 4) illuminate the photosensor with that new LED (which is always on). 5) see if the spikes are still there. If they are - then the problem is not with your LED and its current driver.

Comment: @KevinWhite I believe the power supply is steady. I'm powering the current driver from a precision voltage reference (REF195GSZ-REEL), which gets it's power from a battery. I think that if there is any voltage sag, it would probably stabilize very quickly (unlike the 4 seconds we are seeing here). Also if there was voltage sag, wouldn't the voltage creep up to stability, instead of spike?

Comment: @IgorG I did something similar to this. I bypassed the current driver altogether by powering the LED through a separate circuit with just a battery, a mechanical switch, a resistor, and the LED. I saw the effect still happen. That told me that it either had to be due to the LED or the photodiode.

Comment: @TroyC - can you disrupt the light path between the LED and the sensor. If so you can modulate the light without changing power to the LED. That will determine whether the issue is in the LED or the sensor.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, I agree, I think this experiment will be most telling if I mechanically disrupt the light path. I plan to make an experiment to do this, but it requires some engineering to implement this into my system, so it will take me a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light output of an LED is dependent on the junction temperature, light output decreases as temperature increases. Even at low currents, the junction temperature will rise slightly. The time constant of your curves is consistent with thermal effects.

[image]

https://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/NLPIP/lightingAnswers/LED/heat.asp

Unfortunately, I can't find the details of the experiments used to create these graphs. I would assume that a constant current source was used.

To confirm the junction temperature theory, you need to change the ambient temperature of the LED without changing any other variable. Heat would be easier since cold can create condensation. Heat your LED with a resistor (~ 1/2 W in a 1 W resistor) or other heat source and see if the output changes. It will still have a similar spike and curve, but the levels at the top of the square wave should change slightly. At ambient temperature, on your first graph, the voltage peaks at about 3.673 V and after 10 seconds is about 3.627 V.

Be careful not to change the temperature of the sensor, its output probably changes over temperature also.

Comment: Hi Mattman, I also suspect it may be temperature. I know temperature does greatly effect LED output, and I even compensate for ambient temperature fluctuations in my measurements. However I'm trying to rationalize how the junction temperature warmup period could be so long. I haven't been able to find any information regarding warmup time for an LED. Do you have any insight? I also wonder how oximeters work around this - being a sensitive instrument that measures flashing light.

Comment: If you measure the voltage across the LED you may be able to see the effect of temperature change - an LED will probably have -3-5mV/deg of temperature sensistitivity.

Comment: @TroyC - the LED junction is small, but there are thermal paths to pull the heat away, the junction is either embedded in resin, or mounted on something. I probably have enough parts to duplicate your setup, what is the part number of the LED so I can pick one close to yours? I have an OPT101 and current sources.

Comment: @TroyC - I attempted to duplicate your setup. I can only easily put 5 mA through the LED. This isn't enough to change the light output enough to measure with the OPT101. How much current are you putting through your LED?

Comment: @TroyC - I also taped a 1 W 100 ohm resistor to the LED and put 1/2 W into it. The light output decreases about 5% after it stabilizes. It takes about 2 minutes to stabilize. If the LED is generating the heat, the time constant would be lower.

Comment: @Mattman944 Wow, thanks for putting in the effort! The LED im using is a AP2012SF4C-P22. It only takes about 3mA to saturate the OPTI101 with internal gain. The peak wavelength of the LED aligns nicely with the OPTI101 peak sensitivity wavelength as well, so that probably helps. My setup is totally enclosed in darkness, and the LED and OPTI are about 1/4" apart.

Comment: @Mattman944 Re your comment that the if the LED is generating the heat, the time constant would be slower. Are you suggesting it is not the LED? Can you elaborate on this? Yes it does take some time for the LED to stabilize overall. The experiment I showed was after the system had already stabilized ~ 15 minutes.

Comment: @TroyC - sorry, ambiguous comment by me. Lower time constant value would be a faster response. I am still thinking that it is due to LED heating. Your light output change is only about 1%. Your LED is considerably smaller than mine, I don't have any SMD LEDs. I will make some more measurements when the sun goes down. I have a huge window in my room and I am having trouble excluding all the ambient light.

Comment: @TroyC - I fine tuned my setup and was able to detect about 1/2 percent change in light output as the LED warmed up. I had to use a voltmeter, my scope doesn't have enough sensitivity. My LED is a cheap red through-hole part, it is significantly larger than your SMD part, so it warms up more slowly.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thanks for all your effort. I am also pretty confident now that it is due to LED heating. Today I tried several different SMD LEDs, and they all had the same effect. I also did some more experiments: I dropping the current lower rather than turned it off, then brought it back up. I also tried mechanically blocking the light (which did fix it, however this is a cumbersome solution). I'll add my results in the question for all to see.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was the most helpful.

Comment: If you switch between two equivalent heat sources, that should give you better results. In other words, do a binary search to find the right resistor that produces the same amount of heat as the LED, then when you turn the LED off, turn the "resistor heater" on. Make sure the "resistor heater" is thermally tied well to the LED, and the LED will always be "warmed-up" so when you turn it on, there will be much less of a change (there will always be some). If you can provide more heat sink, then the temperature to which it stabilizes will be lower. Using those 2 ways will get better results.

Answer (score 0):

I would try modifying the circuit so that the current source feeds the LED full-time. Then use your transistor or MOSFET to put a short across the LED.

This allows the current source to remain in its operating range at all times.

Do note this inverts the logic level.

Comment: Hi Dwayne, this is an interesting idea, I'll give it a shot.